# Error al crear input text mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

estoy armando un formulario de votaciones lo cual estoy teniendo problemas al querer crear solo 5 campos input text mediante javascript

```
<form id="formAltaTest" method="POST" class="mainForm">
  <fieldset>
  <div class="rowElem noborder allUpperFull">
    <div class="body" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
      <label>Tema: </label>
      <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $bId ?>' name='bIdTest' id='bIdTest'/>
      <input type="text" name="temaTest" id="temaTest" placeholder="Tema" maxlength="200" style="width: 200px;"/>
    </div>        
  </div>
  <div class="rowElem">
    <div class="body" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
      <label>N. de opciones: </label>
      <input type="text" id="num_opc" name="num_opc" onChange="validarSiNumero(this.value);" value="0" style="width: 100px;">
      <a href="#" id="numOpc" onclick="addFields()"><img width="18" height="18" src="images/icons/notifications/add.png"></a> (max. 5)
      <div class="rowElem">
        <br>
        <div id="ag_opcionales"/></div> 
        <div class="fix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowElem">
    <div class="body" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
      <label>Aclaraciones:</label>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="" name="aclaracionTest" id="aclaracionTest" maxlength="500" style="width: 300px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="fix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowElem">
    <input type="button" id='altaVotacionTest' class="greenBtn" style='float:right;margin:10px;' name="confirmarTemaTest" value="Confirmar" />
    <div class="fix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fix"></div>
  <fieldset>            
</form>
```

Como veran la imagen al hacerle click crea un input text, por lo cual eso esta bien, pero si pones un número mayor 5 igual crea campo, es decir que solo quiero que se creen 5 input como mucho.

Aquí dejo el javascript

```
             <script type='text/javascript'>
                    function addFields(){
                        // Número de INPUT Text que se crearan
                        var number = document.getElementById("num_opc").value;
                        // div donde se colocará el contenido dinámico en este caso ag_opcionales
                        var container = document.getElementById("ag_opcionales");
                        // Borra los contenidos anteriores del div.
                        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);

                        }
                        if (!/^([0-5])*$/.test(numero)) {
                            jAlert("Solo se puede crear 5 opciones");
                           $('#num_opc').focus();
                           return false;
                       }else{
                        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                            // Añadir un nodo con un texto aleatorio.
                            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Opción " + (i+1) + ":"));
                            // Crea un elemento input estableciendo tipo y nombre.
                            var input = document.createElement("input");
                            input.type = "text";
                            input.placeholder = "Coloque su respuesta personalizada";
                            input.name = "number_opc" + i;
                            container.appendChild(input);
                            // Crea un salto de linea, para que se vea mas bonito.
                            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    function validarSiNumero(numero){
                        //Crea un alerta cuando se coloca una letra y no un número en el input.
                        if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(numero))
                           jAlert("El valor " + numero + " no es un número");
                    }
                </script>
```

Intente con ese IF pero tira error al decir que numero no es una variable, y que no se encuentra, pero si la cambio por la variable de num_opc cualquier número que coloque me tira el alert.

A lo que voy y lo que quiero hacer es cuando se coloque por ej un número mayor a 5 en el input num_opc, y se haga click en la imagen este tire un alert avisando que solo se pueden crear 5 input text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El valor del `input#num_opc` lo estás guardando en una variable `number` y no `numero` como la estás llamando al momento de hacer la comparación, después de cambair esto el código funciona correctamente tal y como lo esperas.

```js
function addFields(){
  // Número de INPUT Text que se crearan
  var number = document.getElementById("num_opc").value;
  // div donde se colocará el contenido dinámico en este caso ag_opcionales
  var container = document.getElementById("ag_opcionales");
  // Borra los contenidos anteriores del div.
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
      container.removeChild(container.lastChild);

  }
  if (!/^([0-5])*$/.test(number)) {
      alert("Solo se puede crear 5 opciones");
     $('#num_opc').focus();
     return false;
 }else{
  for (i=0;i<number;i++){
      // Añadir un nodo con un texto aleatorio.
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Opción " + (i+1) + ":"));
      // Crea un elemento input estableciendo tipo y nombre.
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      input.placeholder = "Coloque su respuesta personalizada";
      input.name = "number_opc" + i;
      container.appendChild(input);
      // Crea un salto de linea, para que se vea mas bonito.
      container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
  }
}
function validarSiNumero(numero){
  //Crea un alerta cuando se coloca una letra y no un número en el input.
  if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(numero))
     alert("El valor " + numero + " no es un número");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formAltaTest" method="POST" class="mainForm">
  <fieldset>
  <div class="rowElem noborder allUpperFull">
    <div class="body" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
      <label>Tema: </label>
      <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $bId ?>' name='bIdTest' id='bIdTest'/>
      <input type="text" name="temaTest" id="temaTest" placeholder="Tema" maxlength="200" style="width: 200px;"/>
    </div>        
  </div>
  <div class="rowElem">
    <div class="body" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
      <label>N. de opciones: </label>
      <input type="text" id="num_opc" name="num_opc" onChange="validarSiNumero(this.value);" value="0" style="width: 100px;">
      <a href="#" id="numOpc" onclick="addFields()"><img width="18" height="18" src="images/icons/notifications/add.png"></a> (max. 5)
      <div class="rowElem">
        <br>
        <div id="ag_opcionales"/></div> 
        <div class="fix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowElem">
    <div class="body" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
      <label>Aclaraciones:</label>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="" name="aclaracionTest" id="aclaracionTest" maxlength="500" style="width: 300px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="fix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowElem">
    <input type="button" id='altaVotacionTest' class="greenBtn" style='float:right;margin:10px;' name="confirmarTemaTest" value="Confirmar" />
    <div class="fix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fix"></div>
  </fieldset>            
</form>
```

Comment: Genial, se entendió a la perfección, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!